# How add AuthController add role default IdentityCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

How to add default role when use IdentityCore during registration user: 
My AuthController And Use class UserMenager and SignInManager, IConfiguration, I want to add a role during user registration. I have 3 models responsible for the user and roles. One user can have many roles but here he assumes that the user has one role, eg a student, one role can have many users.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;

    public AuthController(IConfiguration config,
        IMapper mapper,
        UserManager<User> userManager,
        SignInManager<User> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _config = config;
    }

    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(UserForRegisterDto userForRegisterDto)
    {
        var userToCreate = _mapper.Map<User>(userForRegisterDto);

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);

        var userToReturn = _mapper.Map<UserForDetailedDto>(userToCreate);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetUser", 
                new { controller = "Users", id = userToCreate.Id }, userToReturn);
        }

        return BadRequest(result.Errors);
    }
```

Modele database UserRole:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

model Roles:

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

model User

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{ ...public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the `User` you created with `CreateAsync()` and then use [`UserManager.AddToRoleAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1.addtoroleasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1):

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userToCreate, userForRegisterDto.Password);
User newUser = _userManager.Users.First(x => x.Email == userForRegisterDto.Email);
var roleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newUser, "YourDefaultRoleName");
```